# Where is the product form in Magento backend?

Tags: magento

I need to pre-define the SKU value when adding new product. The problem is I couldn't find where the SKU input field is defined. It seems the product form is created dynamically.

Magento 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the default attribute value in the table. It's quite OK for Magento, but you should be careful, as when getting an empty object in the code, the product should also have a predefined SKU.

That can be done in any setup file of your extension the following way (can be done with any attribute):

https://gyazo.com/553d021b19049eb0169fafcf26ab3fea

In the extension Config (config.xml), use the class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup:

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Module_Name</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </module_setup>
        .....
```

If you are using a different class, you can create a new object for this class and implement these actions during the process of installing it.

If this option is not ok for you, you can use the JS code to fill out this field during installation.  This is how to do it:

- Update the layout, and add your JS file (in my case it is js/custom.js):
  https://gyazo.com/cefc1ddd1c1a50c7de82dba2908c687f
- In the file write simple code, that will fill out the predefined SKU value in case it is not found while loading the page 
  https://gyazo.com/27ae4d61c04ea7f1b7a009f127dc32d3

As a result, you will get the same results but with no risk to get errors in code: 
https://gyazo.com/9ccb9589f236ef0a53a21305a307d126